# GitHub is not showing output cells from .ipynb files

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-desktop

I am using VsCode to write my .ipynb codes, and GitHub Desktop to push the files to repositories in GitHub.

When opening the code file in VsCode I can see both input and output cells. Meanwhile after pushing the files to GitHub I can see all input cells and some output cells only when they contain figures or tables, otherwise the output cells are not shown.

For example when the input cell contains (print command) I can see the result printed on VsCode in an output cell, but in Github the output cell will be either empty or does not exist.

Previously I did not face this problem, and I do not recall changing anything in the settings in GitHub, VsCode, GitHub Desktop.

Anyone has an idea what could be the problem ?  Thanks alot in advance.

I'll attach some screenshots :
1-1- Input and output in VsCode:
[image]
1-2- same input cell in GitHub with no output cell at all!

[image]

2-1- Anthore input and output cell at VsCode:

[image]

2-2 - Same input cell in GitHub with empty output cell :

[image]

Comment: Similar issue I am facing. In GitHub repository my Jupyter Notebooks (with .ipynb extension) are not showing the outputs in the output cells. Yesterday everything was fine. But from today I see .ipynb files are not being rendered in my github repositories, what just happened!!! Tried to figure out from this [link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3035), but no solution yet. For urgency, you can always paste the jupyter notebook url in https://nbviewer.org/ to share it.

Answer (score 2):

I cut a ticket with GitHub for the same issue. They have confirmed it to be a bug with their renderer. You can verify it's the same problem by checking the raw notebook file for an output block. If text is there but not rendered, GitHub say they have a few reports of the problem and are working on a fix.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).